# How to mark specific chat bubble in Chat Adapter

Tags: java, android, chat, android-arrayadapter, adapter

I have a group chat, and i want to mark a specific message (those sent when `isProducer` is `true`). The problem is that it marks all the messages all together... 
This is my `Adapter` code:

```
if(customer_id.equals(message.getUserId()))
            isMe = true;
        if(message.getUserId().equals(producer_id))
            isProducer = true;

        if (isMe) {
            holder.imageRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imageLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.body.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT);

        } else {
            holder.imageLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imageRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.body.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        }

        holder.body.setText(message.getBody());
        if (isProducer) {
            holder.body.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }
```

Thnx!

Comment: add `else` to `if (isProducer)` and set default font there

Comment: Nope, sorry, it did not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
isMe = customer_id.equals(message.getUserId()); 
    isProducer = message.getUserId().equals(producer_id);

    if (isMe) {
        holder.imageRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.imageLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.body.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT);

    } else {
        holder.imageLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.imageRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.body.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
    }

    holder.body.setText(message.getBody());
    if (isProducer) {
        holder.body.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    } else {
        holder.body.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL); // Or anything else
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(customer_id.equals(message.getUserId()))
            isMe = true;
        if(message.getUserId().equals(producer_id))
            isProducer = true;

        if (isMe) {
            holder.imageRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imageRight.setbackground(R.drawable.rightimg);
            holder.imageLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.body.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT);

        } else {
            holder.imageLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imageRight.setbackground(R.drawable.leftimg);
            holder.imageRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.body.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        }

        holder.body.setText(message.getBody());
        if (isProducer) {
            holder.body.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }
```

}

you can user R.drawable.leftimg and R.drawable.rightimg should be ninepatch image